# What is the main difference between 'void method' and 'return type method' in Java?

Tags: java, methods, return-type

```
public void printString(String str) {
    System.out.println(str);
}

public String stringMethod(String str) {
    return str;
}
```

I have write the code with two methods, one is void (print the string message) and second is return the String. So those two are the almost same, the difference is just return statement in String method. Can anybody explain those two with real life examples?

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been downvoted so many times. As a Java beginner (with not-so-good teachers as it turns out!), I find this question useful because I have the same question myself.

Answer (score 3):

I shall try to explain the best I can:

```
public void printString(String str) {
     System.out.println(str);
}
```

The "void" return type means that this method doesn't have a return type. It actually doesn't need one because you "print" your String onto the System's output stream.
In an application, this approach may be used to print runtime specific messages on the console for example.

```
public String stringMethod(String str) {
    return str;
}
```

This other method on the other hand, returns a String. This means that you can use the returned value in your code for further processing.
I guess good examples of such methods are "getters". These methods return field values of an object.

For example take the object Person:

```
import java.lang.String;

public class Person {

    private String name;
    private String surename;
    private int age;


    public Person(String name, String surename, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.surename = surename;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Person: " + surename + ", " + name + ". Age: " + age;
    }

    public void printPerson() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }
}
```

Here you can see that the printPerson() uses the toString() method's returned value to print the result on the output stream.